# Multiple definition error is NOT happening when it should

Tags: c++, linker, arm, multiple-definition-error

I have a header header.hxx like this:

```
// header.hxx
#ifndef HEADER1
#define HEADER1
typedef struct s_ringreader{
  // some stuff in header
} RingReader;

RingReader defaultReader;

#endif
```

and multiple cxx like this, source1.cxx

```
// source1.cxx

# include "header.hxx"

void fun1(){
 // some stuff using defaultReader
}
```

, source2.cxx

```
// source2.cxx

# include "header.hxx"

void fun2(){
 // some other stuff using defaultReader
}
```

and source3.cxx

```
// source3.cxx

# include "header.hxx"

void fun3(){
 // some other stuff using defaultReader
}
```

My question is, should I not be getting mutliple definition errors, as I am including the header three times? Theoritically, in order for not getting this error I shoul use either `static` or `extern` for `RingReader defaultReader` but this is not happening.

As a note, this happens with some version of arm-poky compiler, but not with a different version. Is there any cases (like a different compilier) where these situations are not treated like errors?

Comment: One Definition Rule violations are usually not required to be diagnosed. Compiler behaviour is correct as far as standard goes.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen If this is true, which definition would the compiler take in case of ODR violation?

Comment: Breaking the one-definition rule is undefined behaviour (no diagnostic required) - so your compiler is still correct according to the standard.  Practically, with a traditional "compile then link" toolchain, you won't get a diagnostic when *compiling* (due to separate compilation - the compiler, by design, knows nothing about contents of one source file while compiling another) but will usually only get diagnostics when *linking* due to multiple definitions of `defaultReader`  (due to the linker seeing three distinct objects with that name, one in each object file).

Comment: @learning_dude Anything can happen, especially because there are two tools involved. It's possible for example that compiler will optimise any access within translation unit and then linker will see there are no cross-TU accesses to that variable and won't use it at all. The only source that could tell what happens is your toolchain (or better yet, the source code of it).

Comment: [One Definition Rule](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition#One_Definition_Rule): _"...One and only one definition of every non-inline function or variable that is odr-used (see below) is required to appear in the __entire program__ ... The compiler is not required to diagnose this violation, but the behavior of the program that violates it is undefined."_ and _"...Otherwise, the program is ill-formed, __no diagnostic required__...."_

Comment: A C++ toolset may diagnose it or not but programmer should expect any positive result to be illusionary.

Comment: Don’t “fix” this with `static`; that just invites further ODR violations.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen Thank you all for your answers . As a last question, how/where is this ODR diagnose set? Where in the toolchain can I set this?

Comment: @learning_dude it's not set anywhere that's what _"...no diagnostic required..."_ means.  It's practically impossible to diagnose all One Definition Rule violations. You  the programmer are required to not break the rule and there is no way for your toolchain to help you in every case.

Answer (score 0):

Since this code is valid C as well as C++, certain compilers will as an extension (C11 §J.5.11) interpret uninitialized global variables as **common symbols**.  These act like C++17 inline variables and are merged at link time.  This interpretation (like any other whatsoever!) is conforming for a C++ implementation since the program is ill-formed, no diagnostic required.